# How to reattach/rebind Events on Ajax loaded Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento2

Om my website **add to cart ** is done ajax. now I have a button that insert new products via ajax on page. My problem is that the newly added product **add to cart form** do not work with ajax.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <form action="add-to-cart.php?product_id=1">....</form>
  </li>
  <li>
    <form action="add-to-cart.php?product_id=2">....</form>
  </li>
<li>
    <form action="add-to-cart.php?product_id=3">....</form>
  </li>
<li>
    <form action="add-to-cart.php?product_id=4">....</form>
  </li>
<li>
    <form action="add-to-cart.php?product_id=5">....</form>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="load-more">Load More Products</a>
```

I know i can bind event  like this

```
$(document).on("submit", 'form', function(event) { 
    //logic here
});
```

But I do not have access to js file which have the logic (Lets say i can not edit the file).

So my Question is can i reattach/ rebind the event on the newly loaded ajax content(add to cart form to be specific).

**EDIT**
The code of the existing addto cart js file

```
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($, $t) {
    "use strict";

    $.widget('mage.catalogAddToCart', {

        options: {
            processStart: null,
            processStop: null,
            bindSubmit: true,
            minicartSelector: '[data-block="minicart"]',
            messagesSelector: '[data-placeholder="messages"]',
            productStatusSelector: '.stock.available',
            addToCartButtonSelector: '.action.tocart',
            addToCartButtonDisabledClass: 'disabled',
            addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding: '',
            addToCartButtonTextAdded: '',
            addToCartButtonTextDefault: ''
        },

        _create: function() {
            if (this.options.bindSubmit) {
                this._bindSubmit();
            }
        },

        _bindSubmit: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.element.on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                self.submitForm($(this));
            });
        },

        isLoaderEnabled: function() {
            return this.options.processStart && this.options.processStop;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for the form 'submit' event
         *
         * @param {Object} form
         */
        submitForm: function (form) {
            var addToCartButton, self = this;

            if (form.has('input[type="file"]').length && form.find('input[type="file"]').val() !== '') {
                self.element.off('submit');
                // disable 'Add to Cart' button
                addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);
                addToCartButton.prop('disabled', true);
                addToCartButton.addClass(this.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
                form.submit();
            } else {
                self.ajaxSubmit(form);
            }
        },

        ajaxSubmit: function(form) {
            var self = this;
            $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentLoading');
            self.disableAddToCartButton(form);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                        $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
                    }
                },
                success: function(res) {
                    if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                        $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
                    }

                    if (res.backUrl) {
                        window.location = res.backUrl;
                        return;
                    }
                    if (res.messages) {
                        $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
                    }
                    if (res.minicart) {
                        $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                        $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
                    }
                    if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                        $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                            .removeClass('available')
                            .addClass('unavailable')
                            .find('span')
                            .html(res.product.statusText);
                    }
                    self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
                }
            });
        },

        disableAddToCartButton: function(form) {
            var addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding = this.options.addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding || $t('Adding...');
            var addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);
            addToCartButton.addClass(this.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
            addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding);
            addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextWhileAdding);
        },

        enableAddToCartButton: function(form) {
            var addToCartButtonTextAdded = this.options.addToCartButtonTextAdded || $t('Added');
            var self = this,
                addToCartButton = $(form).find(this.options.addToCartButtonSelector);

            addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextAdded);
            addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextAdded);

            setTimeout(function() {
                var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Cart');
                addToCartButton.removeClass(self.options.addToCartButtonDisabledClass);
                addToCartButton.find('span').text(addToCartButtonTextDefault);
                addToCartButton.attr('title', addToCartButtonTextDefault);
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

    return $.mage.catalogAddToCart;
});
```

Comment: i thought you had answered yourself . Because $(document).on("submit", 'form', function(event) { 
    //logic here
}); thats way to rebind the events that created dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all, I have found out the solution. I have called again add to cart method after the ajax call and it worked.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    url:url,
    success: function(data){
        var data =  $($.parseHTML(data));
        var productList = data.find('.products.list').html(); 
        productWrapper.append(productList);
        $( "form" ).catalogAddToCart();  // this solved the problem
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try loading that javascript file after ajax call -

```
$.getScript(src);
```

Comment: The file is loaded by require.js, so getting error while reloading the file

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try loading require.js again.

Comment: I think that is not a good idea. I have edited the Question to include the addtocart js file. If it helps